# Capturing the newly created file input and redirecting it to gz on the fly

Tags: windows, powershell, io, gzip, filesystemobject

Short description of the business case:

- Platform: Windows
- me: BI background, incidental batch/Powershel coding (with google support :-)
- an external tool is creating huge file_name.csv files in a given catalog
- I have no possibility of changing the tool's behavior
- I would like to force (possibly on Operating system level) that whenever such a file is being created in that catalog, something would redirect the stream to gzip and create file_name.csv.gz (on the fly)

I could try to use this to notice that the file is being created:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b

but have no idea how to get the input to gzip instead of the file that the tool is writing to.

The situation in which:

- the tool is writing to a file file_name.csv
- but at the same time the stream of data is passed as the input to gzip
- as a result 2 files are created

would also be OK (it might even be safer because I am not sure if the tool will not require that file_name.csv to exist to finish the export successfully).

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Why not just turn on file system compression, and let the operating system deal with it?  (You might not get quite as good compression, but it would be an awful lot less work.)

Comment: I need this *.gz file to send it to AWS to be imported to Redshift. I wanted to skip that intermediate stage when *.csv is created and go straight to creating *.gz file.

Comment: this looks like a lot of extra work? just compress the files every one hour or every day or whatever and upload them (scheduled task).

Comment: They are large files (15 GB csv , 3GB compressed). And compressing the file on the fly while generating the content would save us some precious minutes and seems to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Maybe, but you'd need a file system filter driver to do it.  That's a pretty steep learning curve for someone with no kernel programming experience.  (If you can spend money, I believe there might be third-party products available that might take care of the difficult parts for you.  That's off-topic here though.)

Comment: Thank you for comments. There is some hope that maybe there will be an option available in that exporting tool to put this csv content directly to *.gz on the fly. This would be the best.

Comment: Anyway I am still curious if there is some easy trick available to capture a file input and redirect it somewhere else :)